# MUI Autocomplete not updating selected value when switching selected values between 2 autocomplete components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have two autocomplete components and an element that when clicked switches the values between the 2 autocomplete components. I am also switching the options when I do this. In the autocomplete components, I am rendering a hidden field with the selected value. When I click the element that switches the values, I can see in the DOM that the hidden field is being updated correctly between the 2 autocomplete components. I can also see the options being switched when I click on the dropdown. But the label/text field is not being updated. The original label is persisted and not updated to the new label.

Parent component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, Suspense } from 'react';

import classes from './AirForm.module.css';

const AirType = React.lazy(() => import('./Controls/Air/AirType'));
const Airport = React.lazy(() => import('./Controls/Air/Airport'));

const AirForm = props => {
    const [airTypeSelected, setAirTypeSelected] = useState('RoundTrip');
    const [fromSelected, setFromSelected] = useState();
    const [fromOptions, setFromOptions] = useState([]);
    const [toSelected, setToSelected] = useState();
    const [toOptions, setToOptions] = useState([]);
    //const [switchFromTo, setSwitchFromTo] = useState(true);

    const switchFromToHandler = () => {
        setFromOptions(toOptions);
        setToOptions(fromOptions);
        setFromSelected(toSelected);
        setToSelected(fromSelected);
        //setSwitchFromTo(!switchFromTo);
    }

    //useEffect(() => {
    //    setFromSelected(toSelected);
    //    setToSelected(fromSelected);
    //}, [switchFromTo]);

    return (
        <Suspense>
            <AirType airTypeSelected={airTypeSelected} setAirTypeSelected={setAirTypeSelected} />
            <form action={props.data.AirUrl} method="post">
                <div className={classes.destinations}>
                    <div>
                        <Airport data={props.data} name="DepartureAirport" label="From" options={fromOptions} setOptions={setFromOptions} optionSelected={fromSelected} setOptionSelected={setFromSelected} onSwitch={switchFromToHandler} includeSwitch={true} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Airport data={props.data} name="ArrivalAirport" label="To" options={toOptions} setOptions={setToOptions} optionSelected={toSelected} setOptionSelected={setToSelected} includeSwitch={false} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </Suspense>
    );
}

export default AirForm;
```

Component containing the autocomplete component:

```js
import React, { useState, useMemo, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import Styles from '../../../../../Theming/Styles';
import classes from './Airport.module.css';

import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress';
import { debounce } from '@mui/material';

const Airport = props => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
    const [searching, setSearching] = useState(true);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const abortConRef = useRef();

    const fetchData = useMemo(() =>
        debounce((request, callback) => {
            if (!props.data.AirportLookupUrl) {
                callback({ success: false });
                return;
            }
            if (abortConRef.current) abortConRef.current.abort();
            abortConRef.current = new AbortController();
            fetch(props.data.AirportLookupUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ q: request }),
                signal: abortConRef.current.signal
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
                callback(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                if (error.name !== 'AbortError') {
                    throw error;
                }
            });
        }, 400),
        []
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        if (inputValue === '') {
            props.setOptions([]);
            return undefined;
        }
        setLoading(true);
        setSearching(true);
        fetchData(inputValue, (result) => {
            setLoading(false);
            setSearching(false);
            if (result.success) {
                const newOptions = result.value.map(val => {
                    const label = `(${val.Code})${val.City && ' ' + val.City} - ${val.Name}`;
                    return {
                        label: label,
                        value: val.Code
                    };
                });
                props.setOptions(newOptions);
            } else {
                props.setOptions([]);
            }
        });
    }, [inputValue, fetchData]);

    return (
        <>
            <Autocomplete
                disablePortal
                options={props.options}
                value={props.optionSelected}
                autoComplete
                autoHighlight={true}
                includeInputInList
                fullWidth
                onChange={(event, value) => { props.setOptionSelected(value); }}
                onInputChange={(event, value) => {
                    if (event.type === 'change') {
                        setInputValue(value);
                    }
                }}
                noOptionsText={searching ? 'Type to search' : 'No options'}
                loading={loading}
                sx={Styles}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                    <>
                        <input type="hidden" name={props.name} value={props.optionSelected?.value} />
                        <TextField
                            {...params}
                            label={props.label}
                            InputProps={{
                                ...params.InputProps,
                                endAdornment: (
                                    <>
                                        {loading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} /> : null}
                                        {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                                    </>
                                )
                            }}
                        />
                    </>
                )}
            />
            {props.includeSwitch && <div onClick={props.onSwitch} className={classes.switch}><i class="fas fa-sync" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>}
        </>
    );
};

export default Airport;
```

UPDATE

Here is a codesandbox. Not sure why it isn't running in stackoverflow but if you navigate to the sandbox it will run. https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-hertz-d8rtb8
If you select an option in either of the autocomplete components and then click switch button, you will see that the options switched but the selected option doesn't change. A hidden field is rendered for each autocomplete and when you click switch button you can see the hidden field's value is updated correctly but autocomplete displayed text value is never updated.

```html
<iframe src="https://codesandbox.io/embed/strange-hertz-d8rtb8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark"
 style="width:100%; height:500px; border:0; border-radius: 4px; overflow:hidden;"
 title="strange-hertz-d8rtb8"
 allow="accelerometer; ambient-light-sensor; camera; encrypted-media; geolocation; gyroscope; hid; microphone; midi; payment; usb; vr; xr-spatial-tracking"
 sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
   ></iframe>
```

UPDATE 2

The issue was because I was not setting the initial state for the selected option. Setting the state has fixed the issue.

Comment: Please make a codesandbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution:**

For solution on your codesandbox you need 2 steps to fix your problem;

1. Make selected useStates initial values `null` inside `App.js`

```
    const [fromSelected, setFromSelected] = useState(null);
    const [toSelected, setToSelected] = useState(null);
```

2. Add optional chaining on `onInputChange` `event` inside `MyAutocomplete`. Since input change happens on controlled state this is not an event and it was failing.

```
onInputChange={(event, value) => {
 if (event?.type === "change") {
  setInputValue(value);
 }
}}
```

---

**Suggestions:**

Also there are couple of possible improvements i can suggest on here;

1. Using multiple hook is dangerous because each of them rerender the component and their values. You can combine your hooks like following;

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState({
   from: {
     selected: null,
     options: fromList
   },
   to: {
     selected: null,
     options: toList
   }
 });

//
const handleSetOptions = (area, key, value) => {
   setOptions({
     ...options,
     [area]: {
       ...options[area],
       [key]: value
     }
   });
 };

//From Autocompolete Props, To is same just need to change from in here
options={options.from.options}
setOptions={(value) => handleSetOptions("from", "options", value)}
optionSelected={options.from.selected}
```

2. When updating state you can use previousState. It is same as using state in your example but it is good practice for async and multi hook situations.

```
const switchFromToHandler = () => {
   setOptions((prevOptions) => ({
     from: prevOptions.to,
     to: prevOptions.from
   }));
 };
```

You can check updated version of [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-leavitt-pwgdex?file=/src/App.js)